# Search in site only returns a few files

Tags: sharepoint-search

I have a Teams team with the standard General channel.

Have a weird situation. A few files that were created using 365 and saved to the Teams files tab will show in search, but any files we upload from the past (we are migrating off shared drives) never seem to get indexed.

The /srchvis.aspx page in the SharePoint site says search is allowed and I even tried a re-index, but the search seems to ignore these files. Mostly Word docs.

Answer (score 2):

On top of Paul's comment, make sure that if content approval is enabled that those documents must be approved as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do the uploaded files have a checked in, major version published? Generally speaking, the search indexer won't index files that are in a draft state, or only have minor version (though this depends on document library settings).

If you think everything has been set up correctly for indexing, you might find the Search Query Tool useful to troubleshoot your query, as the files might be in the index, just not being returned by your query.

https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/releases

Finally, though I haven't tried this in SharePoint Online, you might be able to look at the crawl logs to see if the files are being indexed.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/07/get-search-crawl-log-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html

Comment: The files in question all have a version of 1.0 or 2.0. There is no workflow or approval state required that I can see.

Comment: @GlenMcInnis in that case you might need to distinguish whether or not the problem is with indexing, or with the search query. I'll update my answer

Comment: After looking with other team members, the problem is actually specific to me. It seems to be security related, which is extra odd as I am a global admin. When running Check Permissions on the library I have Full Control and Edit, but the Owners group of this site has "Limited Access". Is that the issue?

Comment: Ok, this is where it might get a little fuzzy. Being a global admin won't necessarily give you full access to the content within a site. However, if you are a Site Collection Admin, then you should have access to the documents. If the Owners group has limited access, this might mean that the documents within the library have unique permissions. What happens if you do a check access on one of the documents that isn't showing up in search?